# Best way to map from XML to unmatching POJO

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, transform, pojo

What is the 'correct' way of handling mapping one XML (xmlA) to jaxb generated pojo's that map to a different XML contract (xmlB)

For example, with the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I want to map to the following class

```
public class PART
{
    private String ITEM;

    private String MANUFACTURER;


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [ITEM = "+ITEM+", MANUFACTURER = "+MANUFACTURER+"]";
    }
}
```

where author maps to ITEM and title maps to MANUFACTURER.

Currently I am using xml transforms and then mapping afterwards; is this the best/correct way of doing this? Or what is the industry standard for such an issue.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

Comment: You talk about "jaxb generated pojo's", but you don't show them. They are like classes called `Catalog` and `Book`, so you map a `Book` to a `PART`, after JAXB has unmarshalled the `Book` for you. Don't know why you'd need *both* an xml transform *and* mapping.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* Class names should be mixed-case (`Part`), and field names should be lowercase, or rather camelCase (`item` and `manufacturer`).

---

You can specify the element name on the `@XmlElement` annotation.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
                     "<catalog>\n" +
                     "   <book id=\"bk101\">\n" +
                     "      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>\n" +
                     "      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>\n" +
                     "   </book>\n" +
                     "</catalog>";
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class, PART.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Catalog catalog = (Catalog)u.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        for (PART part : catalog.parts)
            System.out.println(part.toString());
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="catalog")
class Catalog {
    @XmlElement(name="book")
    List<PART> parts;
}

class PART
{
    @XmlElement(name="author")
    private String ITEM;

    @XmlElement(name="title")
    private String MANUFACTURER;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [ITEM = "+ITEM+", MANUFACTURER = "+MANUFACTURER+"]";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
ClassPojo [ITEM = Gambardella, Matthew, MANUFACTURER = XML Developer's Guide]
```

Comment: I am unable to modify the class files for PART, which already have different element names